# See point cloud in rviz

Tags: rviz, pcl, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm trying to view a point cloud that I am generating with an AR Drone in rviz.  I have the transform set as /ardrone_base_link --> /cam_front and using tf_echo I see:

```
rosrun tf tf_echo /ardrone_base_link /cam_front
At time 1395260250.630
- Translation: [0.007, 0.209, -0.001]
- Rotation: in Quaternion [-0.677, 0.034, -0.037, 0.735]
            in RPY [-1.489, -0.000, -0.101]
At time 1395260251.568
- Translation: [0.006, 0.209, -0.001]
- Rotation: in Quaternion [-0.677, 0.034, -0.037, 0.735]
            in RPY [-1.489, -0.000, -0.101]
```

If i do an echo on the /tf I get:

```
rostopic echo /tf
    transforms: 
  - 
    header: 
      seq: 0
      stamp: 
        secs: 1395260346
        nsecs: 276967023
      frame_id: /ardrone_base_link
    child_frame_id: /cam_front
    transform: 
      translation: 
        x: 0.0063893099241
        y: 0.209490348767
        z: -0.000927047945466
      rotation: 
        x: -0.676587213276
        y: 0.0340744443113
        z: -0.0371685138251
        w: 0.734634042674
```

And the tf_monitor:

```
    rosrun tf tf_monitor /ardrone_base_link /cam_front 
RESULTS: for /ardrone_base_link to /cam_front Chain is: /ardrone_base_link -> NO_PARENT -> /ardrone_base_link -> /ardrone_base_link Net delay     avg =
    0.069172: max = 0.21447
```

And I am publishing the point_cloud on /ardrone/point_cloud:

```
rostopic type /ardrone/point_cloud
sensor_msgs/PointCloud2
```

If I do a rostopic echo on the point_cloud I get proper data.

When I try to use rviz on the point_cloud with the above tranform  I get the following errors whenever a new point_cloud message is published:

```
Message from [/drone_stateestimation] has a non-fully-qualified frame_id [1]. Resolved locally to [/1].  This is will likely not work in multi-robot systems.  This message will only print once
```

And the point_cloud never shows up.  I also get message in rviz saying "Showing [0] points from [0] messages."

In my tf broadcase I am doing:

```
tf::StampedTransform t = tf::StampedTransform(tr,ros::Time::now(),"/ardrone_base_link","/cam_front");
```

I think part of the problem is the seq:0 in the rostopic echo /tf never changes, but I don't know how to fix that.  There could be other problems too.  Any ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/141976/see-point-cloud-in-rviz/) by [davidgitz](https://answers.ros.org/users/13551/davidgitz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2014-03-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your pointcloud appears to have the frame_id "1", which is no frame_id that is available in your tf tree. You probably want it to have the frame_id "/cam_front".

You can also test if your pointcloud gets published properly by setting the fixed frame in rviz to "1" (just type it into the box).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1